# Adding structured data / rich snippets to existing code without affecting template

Tags: structured-data, rich-snippets

I've been doing some reading and following some tutorials to implement structured data / rich snippets code into my store. It's been easy to follow and understand, however now I'm in a situation where I'd like to add my MPN (Manufacturer Part Number) to the feed.

I have successfully added other schema micro data by simply adding to existing div classes. The problem is that I have a box that is negatively affected by using a div class in line.

```
         <div class="nicebox" itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
         <?php echo $this->getTierPriceHtml() ?>
         <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('alert_urls') ?>
         <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('product_type_data') ?>         
         <div class="mpn" itemprop="mpn"><p><?php echo $this->__('MPN: ') ?><?php echo $_product->getData('mpn')?></p></div>
         <p><?php echo $this->__('WEB ID: ') ?><?php echo $_product->getId(); ?></p>
          </div>
```

How can I declare an **itemprop** inline with my  code that would not negatively impact the *nicebox* class?

Comment: There is an other way to add it by using a custom extension as the most of them does not effect the template, Here is the one I can share - http://www.fmeaddons.com/magento/rich-snippets-extension.html

Comment: I have had nothing but problems with FME so I stay away

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `div` try and use a `span` which should work better inline. Also the `class` is not required for microdata so you can leave that out